# DotNetBrowser - Select all text on web page

Tags: select, dotnetbrowser

I'm starting integration of DotNetBrowser and I will have questions as I go along. I thought I would submit here first.

My question of the day is how can I programmatically perform a select all on the HTML page currently loaded?

Went through the doc and neither WebBrowser nor BrowserView have methods for performing a select all.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the command which will select all the web page content? If so, you can use the next code snippet: Browser.ExecuteCommand(EditorCommand.SELECT_ALL);

Comment: Yes that would do just fine. I saw that executeCommand method but missed the enum itself so didn't know what to do with it... Thanks!